# Implementing sound file in android from button

Tags: java, android, pointers, audio

I am trying to build an Android application to play a high frequency sound file and also accept that frequency as a trigger, I have a method (from a SO user) but don't know how to trigger it from a button in Android Studio, is there a simple way?

The code is

```
int samplingFreq = 48000;
int numberOfSamplesXSymbol = 48000; //1 sec tone
int f0 = 20000;//ultrasonic tone

for (int i=0;i<numberOfSamplesXSymbol;i++)
{
    tone[i] = Math.cos(2*pi*f0/samplingFreq*i);
}
```

I have a button in the app but don't have any pointer on it...
If anyone can help I would be very grateful.

Comment: use `button.setonclicklistener()` method

Comment: Are you trying to figure out how to play the sound from a button or hooking up the button to do something? confused about what you're asking

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to play the sound from the button.